# Dynamic Documentation module not released for DXA 2.2?

Tags: dxa, tridion-docs, dxa2.2

I see the Dynamic Documentation module available for DXA 2.1 here:
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/releases/tag/DXA_2.1_Release

However, I don't see the equivalent module available for DXA 2.2 here:
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/releases/tag/DXA_2.2

Is there any reason why it was left out of DXA 2.2?

Answer (score 3):

The DXA 2.2 Dynamic Documentation Module (for .NET and Java) will be released later (expected soon).

See https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/product-announcements/posts/sdl-releases-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2

Comment: That's great! I just would have expected the release to coincide with the DXA 2.2 release in Github:

https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/tree/release/2.2

Comment: I was able to find the released module. It would a good idea to update the SDL documentation or the answer since the sdl docs link points to DXA 2.2 release tag and not 2.2_hotfix tag.

https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/releases/tag/DXA_2.2.2_Hotfix